# Understand gdb output in case of segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, pthreads

I have a segfault in my program. I try to use the `backtrace` command of the `gdb` to find the bug, but unfortunately, I do not understand its output:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff1678480 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff171c11e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff17e565f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff17432e3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff16580bf in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff179e758 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff173cea8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#7  0x00007ffff6b8770a in start_thread (arg=0x7fffef352700) at pthread_create.c:333
#8  0x00007ffff68bd82d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

Does anyone know where the segfault comes from? For example, why is the `main` method not listed in the `backtrace`'s output?

Comment: It is backtrace of some thread other than main. Note `clone` at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know where the segfault comes from?

Yes: GDB *told* you where it comes from: an unnamed function at address `0x7ffff1678480` inside `libnvidia-opencl.so.1`

> For example, why is the main method not listed in the backtrace's output?

Because the crash happened in a thread other than the main thread.

So, what should you do?

There is almost nothing you *could* do to understand this crash, because you are using vendor-provided and completely opaque library.

You *should* go over any `OpenCL` calls your program does (assuming it does any) and verify that the arguments you supply are valid and satisfy the OpenCL API requirements.

You should also do `(gdb) thread apply all where` to see where other threads are. Maybe your main thread is exiting without having properly shut down OpenCL.

You could also try to run your program with a different (possibly lower performance) open source OpenCL implementation (such as [pocl](http://pocl.sourceforge.net/)). *IF* the crash reproduces with `pocl`, you'll have much easier time understanding what went wrong, as you can examine the source and GDB will tell you *exactly* where in the source the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the bottom and working up:

```
#8  0x00007ffff68bd82d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

I see a function called `clone`. I type `man clone` locally and get something like [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).

The fourth paragraph is

> One use of clone() is to implement threads: multiple threads of
>   control in a program that run concurrently in a shared memory space.

which seems relevant when I look at the next stack frame

```
0x00007ffff6b8770a in start_thread (arg=0x7fffef352700) at pthread_create.c:333
```

where I see a function called `start_thread` in module `pthread_create`. Hmm, thread, thread, I've seen that word somewhere before. I remember seeing `pthread_create` somewhere before, so type `man pthread_create` ...

Well, that explains why `main` isn't in the stack trace - this is the stack of a child thread. Not the main thread, in which `main` runs.

Note that you can type `info threads` to see what other threads were running at the time the fault occurred, and `thread 1` (or whatever number) to switch to another thread and examine *its* stack.

Comment: "I see a function called `pthread_create`" -- no, you don't. You see a function called `start_thread` defined in a *file* called `pthread_create.c`.